# JavaScript- Not showing the Title in Text Accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

At first Please see the screenshot , here i am working on Accordion text Editor, where you can add title and body text. 
[image]

when i clicked ADD button multiple time then showing like this type. Not showing the title text. i thing it's problem on JS file. Does any solution??
Thanks in Advance!

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#Add_btn').click(function(){
  $('#accordion_body').append($('#editableDiv').html());      
  var x = document.getElementById("accordion_input").value;
  document.getElementById("accordion_title").innerHTML = x;
 });     
});

function myAccorFunction() {
    var Myaccordion = `
        <div class="Myacc" id="acc_main" contenteditable="false"
             class="accordion-main"
             style="position: relative;width: 98.5%; left: 9px;">
        </div>
        <div class="panel-group trash_removed" id="accordion" role="tablist"
             aria-multiselectable="true"
             style="margin-bottom: 7px;margin-top: 10px"
             contenteditable="false">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne"
                 contenteditable="false">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a id="accordion_title" role="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                   data-parent="#accordion" href="#expandingCol"
                   aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                </a><div class="icon_area">
                <i class="fa fa-edit" data-toggle="collapse"
                   data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne"
                   aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                </i>
                <i onclick="myfundelete()" class="fa fa-trash">
                </i>
              </div>
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="expandingCol" class="panel-collapse collapse"
               role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne"> 
            <div id="accordion_body" class="panel-body" >
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    `;
    $("#editor").append(Myaccordion);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myAccorFunction()" id="Add_btn"
        class="btn btn-primary note-image-btn" role="button"
        data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion"
        href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true"
        aria-controls="collapseOne">Add</button>
```

Comment: You are repeating ids.  Not sure if that is your only issue, but that's definitely an issue web standard wise.  Ids should not be repeated within a single document.

Comment: First of all why are you calling two different function in different ways from the same button? and what is editableDiv and editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are using the same element ID `#accordion_title` more than once. As browsers assume [element ID is unique within a page](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_id.asp), `document.getElementById("accordion_title").innerHTML = x;` will only change the innerHTML of the first element having that ID, but not the subsequent ones that were appended by the ADD button.

Try using a Class name instead of ID for your title text element, then iterate over every element of that class to change their innerHTML.

```
$('.accordion_title').each(function() {
    $(this).html($('#accordion_input').val());
});
```

Comment: Glad I could help.